# Impact of attack occured in Radius, DHCP and HTTP servers on VOIP?

Tags: attacks, webserver, attack-prevention, voip, dhcp

Assume we can crash the RADIUS server in a VOIP system. What would be the impact on the confidentiality, integrity, and availability of VOIP service. What would be the impact if the same question if an attack occurred at a web server and a DHCP server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would depend on the how this is implemented (fail open versus fail closed).

But since RADIUS is used as an authentication service, I would say confidentiality and integrity wouldn't be affected (unless you have access to the RADIUS server when crashing the machine). The availability will obviously go down.

Just "crashing" the machines will not necessarily provide you access to the data in those services. If you do get access (root exploit using a buffer overflow that causes to crash the server) then you will indeed void confidentiality and integrity.

Comment: i want to know is it necessary to use an authentication in order to make communication between users (callers) in other words is it necessary that a user make an identification before calling

Comment: You do not need authentication, but what's the use of a line that provides integrity and confidentiality if you don't actually know who's using it? You would have a secure A to B line, but you would never be able to verify who's using it.

Comment: Moreover, given that the web server is used only for administration,I assume that any attack against it
only affect the availability of VoIP. Is it right?

Comment: You should rephrase your question to provide a decent image of what your setup is and what you want to do. What does a webserver have to do with VOIP? What has a dhcp server have to do with VOIP?